# Why has my Windows Phone Dev Centre Dashboard stopped reporting downloads?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

All of my applications report in as published and up, however, I've gone from 60+ daily downloads to absolutely zero across all applications for several days straight. This seems very odd and more like an error in MS reporting on dev.windowsphone.com. Does anyone know why this may have happened? Is anyone else experiencing this problem?

[image: dev.windowsphone.com Highlights Dashboard]

Comment: The question is off topic.  If you are having issues with Microsoft's phone dev center, you need to contact their support.  Also, people often will downvote blatantly off topic questions.  This isn't an abuse of the voting privilege.  For more info, and to request that people downvoting leave a comment, see [meta].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think they have downvoted your question because is not a code related question..

Anyway.. It's a DevCenter's known issue and normally it's resolved within a few days..
All the lost report will be restored, don't worry! It's not the first time!